# website design based on a book?

Tags: language-agnostic

i am wonder how i can create an interactive website where the website is made to function like a book like flipping pages. what language can be used to create this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either flash or javascript.

You can try this service: http://page-flip.com/ or if you want to use jquery: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/page-turn

Answer (score 0):

The page flip effect you are talking about is most commonly done using Adobe Flash.